# PL/SQL: Using two variables in query

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, syntax-error

SQL plus is giving `"from keyword not found where expected"`. I think my query is correct `select ... from ... where`
I think there is a possibility that we cannot use two variables in a query in PL/SQL block (I'm not sure about that).

```
DECLARE
  LHID   NUMBER(1);
  LNOPAT NUMBER(6);
BEGIN
  SELECT HID INTO LHID, 
         NUMPATIENTS INTO LNOPAT 
    FROM HOSPITAL065 
   WHERE HLOCATION='LAHORE';

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('HID:  ' || LHID || ' GOT PATIENTS  ' ||  
                         LNOPAT || '  LOCATED IN         LAHORE');
END;
```

Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use one `into` only:

```
select hid, numpatients
   into lhid, lnopat
....
```